# Connect ClearOS to TorGuard

Tags: vpn, clearos

I'm wondering if it's possible to push all outbound traffic through TorGuard or another VPN service. I tried some google-fu but didn't see that anyone had done this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install OpenVPN client software and connect to TorGuard through that. Just copy the TorGuard OpenVPN config files to your OpenVPN client: https://torguard.net/downloads.php

Comment: I will test this when I get home. (I won't forget to accept, promise)